# Rewrite Rule not working for css, js and images

Tags: php

⁠⁠⁠File structure:

```
htdoc
|--project
   |--admin
      |--css
      |--js
      |--images
      |--.htaccess
      |--index.php
```

.htaccess file contain:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /project/admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?PATH_INFO=$1 [L,QSA]
```

When I going through the following link every thing is working properly.

```
localhost/project/admin/profile
```

But when I going through the following link the css js and images are not loading

```
localhost/project/admin/profile/
```

Index.php
the css link is like that

```
href="css/style.css"
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to just use full path to call css/js/images from a redirected page. eg:
http://localhost/project/admin/css/style.css